# Responsive 5 div elements CSS, one by one

Tags: html, css, responsive, element

I have trouble with 5 div elements to make it responsive.

I have this this div elements like this:

```
<div class="AllCont">
  <div class="ContQuint">
    <div>Here Image 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="ContQuint">
    <div>Here Image 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="ContQuint">
    <div>Here Image 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="ContQuint">
    <div>Here Image 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="ContQuint">
    <div>Here Image 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The style CSS like this:

```
.AllCont {
  display: table;
  border-collapse : collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
.ContQuint {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 20%;
}
```

And trying to do it responsive with this in CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:1540px) {
.ContQuint {
    display: table-row;
  }
}
```

But i dontk want that. I want something like this:

**| Elem 1 - Elem 2 - Elem 3 - Elem 4 - Elem 5 |**

Then when the screen size decreases a little bit I want this:

**| Elem 1 - Elem 2 - Elem 3 - Elem 4 |**

**| Elem 5 |**

Then when decreases more:

**| Elem 1 - Elem 2 - Elem 3 |**

**| Elem 4 - Elem 5 |**

Then a little more:

**| Elem1 - Elem 2 |**

**| Elem 3 - Elem 4 |**

**| Elem 5 |**

And Finally:

**| Elem 1 |**

**| Elem 2 |**

**| Elem 3 |**

**| Elem 4 |**

**| Elem 5 |**

---

How can i do that with CSS or javascript?

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're looking for is `display: inline-block;`! Plus `display: block` on the parent `.AllCont` element. Tables used to be useful for this kind of layout, but these days you'll have a better time checking [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) (or even [CSS grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)) for something more sophisticated.

Answer (score 2):

Should probabliy take a look into responsive layout, this will help you a lot understanding different patterns.

[Responsive patterns by google](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/patterns?hl=en)

Either way i recommend the use of flexboxes or inline/block elements.

> Solution using flexboxes :
>
> ```css
> .AllCont {
>   display: flex;
>   flex-direction: row;
>   flex-wrap: wrap;
>   border-collapse : collapse;
>   width: 100%;
> }
> .ContQuint {
>     width: 200px;
> }
> ```
>
> ```html
> <div class="AllCont">
>   <div class="ContQuint">
>     <div>Here Image 1</div>
>   </div>
>   <div class="ContQuint">
>     <div>Here Image 2</div>
>   </div>
>   <div class="ContQuint">
>     <div>Here Image 3</div>
>   </div>
>   <div class="ContQuint">
>     <div>Here Image 4</div>
>   </div>
>   <div class="ContQuint">
>     <div>Here Image 5</div>
>   </div>
> </div>
> ```
>
> Solution using inline and block elements
>
> ```css
> .AllCont {
>   display: block;
>   border-collapse : collapse;
>   width: 100%;
> }
> .ContQuint {
>   display: inline-block;
>     width: 200px;
> }
> ```
>
> ```html
> <div class="AllCont">
>   <div class="ContQuint">
>     <div>Here Image 1</div>
>   </div>
>   <div class="ContQuint">
>     <div>Here Image 2</div>
>   </div>
>   <div class="ContQuint">
>     <div>Here Image 3</div>
>   </div>
>   <div class="ContQuint">
>     <div>Here Image 4</div>
>   </div>
>   <div class="ContQuint">
>     <div>Here Image 5</div>
>   </div>
> </div>
> ```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: @Pato ur welcome, dont forget to upvote and answer if it solved your question. If not comment in what else i can help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than giving a % width for .ContQuint, give a fixed width. otherwise the width reduces with screen width.

[fiddle showing it](https://jsfiddle.net/6d7avdpr/3/)

```
.ContQuint {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox does this with `flex-wrap: wrap;`

```css
.AllCont {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.ContQuint {

}
```

```html
<div class="AllCont">
  <div class="ContQuint">
    <div>Here Image 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="ContQuint">
    <div>Here Image 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="ContQuint">
    <div>Here Image 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="ContQuint">
    <div>Here Image 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="ContQuint">
    <div>Here Image 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `flex`, `width` + `flex-wrap` and `min-width` to spare a mediaquerie.

```css
.AllCont {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.ContQuint {
  width: 20%;
  /* optionnal*/
  min-width: 300px;/* this is alike your breaking point ... each 300px or else value you set */
  padding: 1px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
img {
  /* optionnal*/
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="AllCont">
  <div class="ContQuint">
    <div>
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ContQuint">
    <div>
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x200"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ContQuint">
    <div>
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x200"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ContQuint">
    <div>
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x200"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ContQuint">
    <div>
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x200"> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[pen to play with](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vjYzXJ)